# Reusing same buffer with glDrawElements (iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vbo

Is it possible to create a **VBO** and reuse it between calls to `glDrawElements` in the same rendering cycle? (I tried and obtained weird results). The example below is missing bindings, etc.

**Init code (executed only once)** **:**

```
glGenBuffers(...)

glBufferData(...)
```

**Render frame code (executed for each frame):**

```
glMapBufferOES(...)
//... Update buffer from index 0 to X
glDrawElements(...)
//... Update buffer from index 0 to Y
glDrawElements(...)
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unmap your buffer before drawing with it. If you don't unmap, that's probably why you're seeing weird results with `glDrawElements`.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMapBuffer.xml

After `glDrawElements` is called, you can remap your buffer and fill it in again.

You will probably get better performance by not reusing the buffer right away. Remapping right after the draw will probably block until the draw is completed.

Comment: Indeed, how could I miss that. Thanks a lot!